# oracle select with php won't show

Tags: php, oracle

here's my code i don't know where i do wrong here

```
    <?php 
$conn=oci_connect("martin","123","localhost/XE");
If (!$conn)
    echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
else
    echo 'Succesfully connected with Oracle DB';?>
 <table border="1">
    <?php $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select*from MsNama");
        oci_execute($stid);

        while ($row = 
     oci_fetch_array(
         $stid,
         OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
 ) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
</tr>
        <?php }?>
```

and here's my select on oracle database:

```
SQL> select * from MsNama
  2  ;
NAMA                      ANGKA G
---------------------- -------- -
martin                        1 m
```

this is what's it's look like
[image: this is what's it's look like]

I changed the code with what i found on internet but still not working

```
<html>
<head><title>Oracle demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
     $conn=oci_connect("martin","123","localhost/XE");
        If (!$conn)
              echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
        else
              echo 'Succesfully connected with Oracle DB';

        ?>
        <table border="1">
        <?php       $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select * from MsNama");
        oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);

        while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
            $empno    = oci_result($stid, "NAMA");
            $ename    = oci_result($stid, "angka");
            $job      = oci_result($stid, "gender");

        ?>
   <tr>
        <td><?php echo $empno; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ename;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $job; ?></td>
   </tr>
        <?php }?>
   </table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

i tried and always no result. nothing showing

Comment: Why There is no gap between `select` & `*` & `from` ?

Comment: doesn't matter still the same after i give a gap between them like you suggested

Comment: do `var_dump($row);` inside `while loop` and see what output comes ?

Comment: You use `OCI_ASSOC` but then try to access numeric indices. Having `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on should tell you that.

Comment: i changed to OCI_NUM but still not working, and using var_dump($row); nothing comes out

Answer (score 0):

oh my code not wrong but here's the code and it worked

```
<html>
<head><title>Oracle demo</title></head>
<body>
<?php 
$conn=oci_connect("martin","123","localhost/XE");
If (!$conn)
    echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
else
    echo 'Succesfully connected with Oracle DB';

 ?>
<table border="1">
<?php       $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select*from MsNama");
            $r=oci_execute($stid);

            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH)) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
    </tr>
            <?php }?>
 </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

the problem that i forgot to commit so .-.there's no result i'm sorry